# Invalid content was found starting with element 'Generator'

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

#### Invalid content was found starting with element 'Generator'.

```
 <hibernate-mapping>
     <class name="com.Test.Example.Employee" table="emp1000">
         <id name="id">
            <generator class="assigned"></generator>
         </id>
        <property name="firstName"></property>
        <property name="lastName"></property>
        <property name="mobNo"></property>
     </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Are you sure the xml-snippet in your answer is the same as in your code? The error states the element `'Generator'` with a capital `G` is invalid, but your code-snippet doesn't even contain a capital 'G'.. Does it look like `<Generator class="assigned"></generator>`, `<generator class="assigned"></Generator>` or `<Generator class="assigned"></Generator>` in your actual code?

Comment: thank you friend that was the mistake... which i founded after posting it.. thank u so much.

Comment: Glad you were already able to fix it. I will post an answer, so you can accept it. That way anyone with the same error as you had can find the answer as well. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code snippet and actual code it probably different. The error states the element `'Generator'` with a capital `G` is invalid, but your code-snippet doesn't even contain a capital 'G'.. Your actual code most likely looks like one of these three:

```
<Generator class="assigned"></generator>
<generator class="assigned"></Generator>
<Generator class="assigned"></Generator>
```

Changing it to lowercase `generator` should fix your issues here.